# Hibernate: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when saving entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, app-config

Code Link: https://github.com/safeeulbashir/springBootWebApp/tree/WithHibernate

I am trying to add some data in my database using hibernateTemplate. But I am getting an exception like bellow
I don't know why it is trying to cast employeeNo to com.safee.model.Employee.

Any help would be appreciated.
Code link is provided above.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.safee.model.Employee.employeeNo to com.safee.model.Employee
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:622) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:618) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:341) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:618) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.safee.DAO.EmployeeDao.addEmployee(EmployeeDao.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.addEmployee(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.safee.service.EmployeeServices.addEmployee(EmployeeServices.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.safee.controller.EmployeeController.addInformation(EmployeeController.java:149) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: in your addEmployee.jsp file you call this : `onsubmit="return validateUpdateform()">` why this ?

Comment: This is for validating the values of the form to check whether it is null or not

Comment: I don't see this javascript function in your addEmployee.jsp but in update.jsp and finally it submit employeeUpdateForm instead of employeeAddForm?? is it normal ? or maybe this method exists somewhere else?

Comment: The main problem that I am facing is it is not being able to map the values that are coming from database.
com.safee.model.Employee cannot be cast to com.safee.model.Employee
Lets not look at the add. I have added one value manually to the database. and trying to view this from my view.jsp. If you go to Employee Controller view function you wil get that I am trying to do there.